# $(-1)^{\sum\limits_{s\in S}s+\sum\limits_{t\in T}t} = (-1)^{\sum\limits_{q\in S+T}q}$

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose $S,T$ are sets of natural numbers and let $\|S\|_1=\sum \limits_{s\in S}s$.

Why is it true that $(-1)^{\|S\|_1+\|T\|_1}=(-1)^{\|S+T\|_1}$?

I think maybe $S+T\ne\{s+t\ :\ s\in S, t\in T\}$ because then with $S=\{0,1,2,3\}$ and $T=\{0,1\}$ we would have

$\|S\|_1=0+1+2+3=6$, $\|T\|_1=0+1=1\ \implies \|S\|_1+\|T\|_1=7$

but $S+T=\{0, 1,2,3,1,2,3,4\}=\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ and $\|S+T\|_1=10$

So one is even and the other is odd.

Unless something else is meant by $S+T$.

Comment: People sometimes use $+$ to denote union.

Comment: @PhicarUnion doesn't work either. Try $S=\{1,2,3\}, T=\{1\}$

Comment: Yes, i did not claim it was. Another one is sum mod 2, the so called symmetric difference (If I recall correctly this notation is used by Tutte)? Perhaps is best if you reference where you find this expression.